# Maven- Significance of ordering of dependencies in POM.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

What is the significance of dependencies in pom.xml?

I have the dependencies in the following order:

1. CGLIB
2. Apache Commons
3. Spring Data
4. Hibernate
5. MySQL Connector
6. Spring

If I insert Spring Security dependencies above Spring, anywhere, I get errors. For example, if I insert the two dependencies at the very top, I get this exception (also a compiler error before running):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/core/env/EnvironmentCapable

Comment: share your pom, difficult to tell like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dependencies order is insignificant in Maven.

After adding your Spring Security dependencies you need to remove your Spring dependency, because Spring Security references a different version of Spring which does contain this class.

So removing Spring dependency should fix this.

Comment: So you mean one can't 2 different dependencies pointing to different versions of spring or any other project?

Comment: If these are transitive dependencies, Maven should do it's job resolving the correct one. In this case @chinmayzen points Maven to override the dependency (Spring) which it should auto-resolve as transitive which creates inconsistency of versions.

Comment: Thanks. I was reading this as well to understand the problem: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/spring-security-with-maven.html (just for info)